# How I can await in a streambuilder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

```
Future<void> _getInfo() async {
      var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(CustomCollectionPath.userInfo)
          .where('email', isNotEqualTo: currentUser.email);
      var querySnapshot = await collection.get();

      for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data();
        var emailCurrentUser = data['email'];
        var matchingBeet = beetsList
            .firstWhere((element) => element.email == emailCurrentUser);
        matchingBeet.user = UserModel(
            id: Random().nextInt(99999),
            name: data['name'],
            urlImage: data['imageUrl'],
            roleDescription: data['description'],
            description: data['description'],
            icon: Icons.abc,
            color: Colors.red);
      }
    }

Future<void> setMarker() async {
      for (var i = 0; i < beetsList.length; i++) {
        BitmapDescriptor markerUser =
            await MarkerIcon.downloadResizePictureCircle(
                beetsList[i].user!.urlImage,
                size: 190,
                addBorder: true,
                borderColor: AppColors.whiteColor,
                borderSize: 24);

        markers.add(Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(beetsList[i].email),
            position: LatLng(beetsList[i].coordinates.latitude,
                beetsList[i].coordinates.longitude),
            onTap: () async {
              await openInfoModalUser(context, beetsList[i].user!);
            },
            icon: markerUser));
      }
    }
```

inside my code in my widget:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection(CustomCollectionPath.beets)
                  .where('email', isNotEqualTo: currentUser.email)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  markers.clear();
                  _getPosition(snapshot.data!.docs);
                  _getInfo();
                  setMarker();
                  return GoogleMap(
                      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                      myLocationEnabled: true,
                      buildingsEnabled: true,
                      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                      markers: markers,
                      mapToolbarEnabled: false,
                      initialCameraPosition: _startPosition);
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              }),
```

The only problem is that when I go to add the marker via setMarker, user is null, because setMarker is called before getInfo, but it must be the other way around.

I need the changes to be in real time because my map has to update the positions instantly.

Since I can't put await in streamBuilder how can i fix it?

Comment: Since `_getInfo` returns a `Future`, did you consider returning a `FutureBuilder` from the `builder` method that you have?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can show me?

Comment: Where you now have `_getInfo();`, replace that with return `FutureBuilder(future: _getInfo(), builder: ....)`

Comment: Except, no, you need to lift the state of _getInfo()'s future out of the build phase, or it will get restarted repeatedly.  When it's this complex, just use Riverpod providers, which can wrap streams and futures in predictable and composable ways.